# ContentLoadException was unhandled - Error loading "Arial". File not found

Tags: c#, xna, hud

I was trying to get a score in my game. But it looks like the loader cant find the font Arial. When I try to run the game I get the error: "Error loading "Arial". File not found"

Game1.cs:

```
HUD hud;

protected override void LoadContent()
{    
      hud = new HUD();
      hud.Font = Content.Load<SpriteFont>("Arial"); // error here
}
```

HUD.cs:

```
public class HUD
    {
        private Vector2 scorePos = new Vector2(20, 10);
        public SpriteFont Font { get; set; }
        public int Score { get; set; }
        public HUD()
        {
        }
        public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
        {

            spriteBatch.DrawString(
                Font,                   
                "Score: " + Score.ToString(),  
                scorePos,                      
                Color.White);                 
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you [added the file to your project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb447673.aspx)?

Comment: I dont think so, what file do I need to add to my project?

Comment: Is there also another way to add a font, doens't matter which font?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XNA requires that fonts be added to your project explicitly before being used.  That is, you can't use "Arial" unless you've added an Arial .spritefont file to your project.

If you're using XNA, you can read on how to add a SpriteFont here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb447673.aspx

If you're using MonoGame you can use the Pipeline tool to add SpriteFonts.  You can read about it here:

http://www.monogame.net/documentation/?page=Pipeline